# How can we know if a snapshot (taken in ESXi) is reverted or not?

Tags: vmware, snapshot, powercli, esxi

I have a ESXi host running a bunch of VMs. All the VMs have their own snapshots taken periodically. My question is how do we know if a given snapshot is committed (applied) or not using both powerCLI and manually(GUI)

Answer (score 1):

**PowerCli:**
Once you have connected to the appropriate vCenter server/ESXi host.

```
$snapShot = get-vm -name $foo | get-snapshot
```

This will return a Snapshot-Object, as detailed here:
https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/PowerCLI/PowerCLI41U1/html/Snapshot.html

From there you can:

```
$snapShot | get-member
```

to see what properties you have to work with.

**As for The Gui:**

Simply right click the vm > snapshot > snapshot manager

Then you will see a hierarchical list of snapshots and also where you currently are in the list.